# Is there away to do sky detection automatically?

Tags: python

I’m trying to make sky detection, I already try on opencv blue color detection, it didn’t work well because of clouds and also because of different color depends on time, the final try was the most useful method, I used a canny detection that need adjusted by user, then I filled the sky with white pixels, and other with black. 
The question is, 
Is it possible to make sky detection automatically without interface from the user ?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can give a recommendation from an AI perspective. Read to the end for a non-AI recommendation.

---

Actually, there does exist a "simple" way given that you are willing to annotate about a few thousand images manually. You can have some of your coworkers/classmates to help you out with this. I worked with the [YOLO-V3](https://pjreddie.com/darknet/yolo/) program which does give you a decent GUI to manually annotate your images. YOLO-V3 however only works with bounding boxes, so my next suggestion will work with identifying the whole sky and segmenting the image pixel by pixel.

But if you already have an annotated dataset, There's a neural network architecture called [Mask RCNN](https://github.com/matterport/Mask_RCNN) which overlays your given image with a mask of any color you choose over a given object or setting you to indicate. This one, from my experience, does take a LOT of annotated data to train on for a decent result. But for something as generalizable as a sky-detector and overlay, it should work well with only 1-3k annotated pictures. If you chose to go down this route, here is an [article](https://engineering.matterport.com/splash-of-color-instance-segmentation-with-mask-r-cnn-and-tensorflow-7c761e238b46) that describes how you can make your own annotated pictures.

---

Non-AI recommendations:

- using the blue color index in the RGB tuple, play around with what thresholds you can use for each color, and you can then do some random sampling of these points and go from there.

---

But seriously, based on everything I researched on this, looking at other people's repositories, it seems the best method is via AI. Here's an [example](https://github.com/MaybeShewill-CV/sky-detector). The reason is detecting a sky takes a lot of spacial "awareness". For example, how will the computer discriminate between the sky and an ocean? Both are blue. But you can see from the waves that it is an ocean. Basic spatial reasoning can really be done by AI or a crap ton of manual coding.